# Unable to Validate flow input using formula

Tags: formula, visual-workflow

I'm trying to validate a flow text element called `subject`. I created a formula called validateSubject with the following logic:

`If(LEN({!Subject})<255,true,false)`

I added this formula to the Validate Input section of the screen on the subject element on the screen. When I debug and put in more than 255 characters, the validation does not stop the flow or display the error message I added to the Validate Input section. I switched it to:

`If(LEN({!Subject})<255,false,true)`

and it stops the flow with the validation error, but even if I have less than 255 characters. What is incorrect with the formula? I would expect that in the first example that if the character limit is less than 255 it would return true and pass the validation.

Comment: You can *always* replace `IF(expression, true, false)` with just `expression`, and `IF(expression, false, true)` with just `NOT(expression)`.

Comment: I changed it to `NOT(LEN({!Subject})<=255)`, which catches it every time no matter how many characters I enter in the subject. I switch it to `NOT(LEN({!Subject})>=255)` then it never catches the validation. I'm sure the answer is staring me in the face, but I don't see it.

Comment: I added the formula directly in the Validate Input instead of using a formula variable and the logic I had in my formula variable worked perfectly. Not sure why it didn't work using the formula variable?

Comment: Probably the formula couldn't evaluate the input entered into the Subject field, maybe because it happens 'off the screen'?